# Options to configure Mass Transit endpoint configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, servicebus, masstransit

I'm new MassTransit Service Bus. What are the options to configure service endpoints besides in code or appSettings in a config file? And what is the preferred method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would just subscribe to a given type via consumers and have publishers. There is not normally any coupling between them other than the message type. So the connections between endpoints or more or less automatically configured based upon metadata.

The [documentation on subscriptions configuration](http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/master/configuration/sub_config_api.html) might be a good place to start to dig into this a little more.

Comment: Thanks, Travis.  I'll look into it.  You guys are doing a great job!

Comment: No problem, if you have further questions, the mailing list is likely a better place for a real discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/masstransit-discuss

Comment: You still need to configure command endpoints, since you Send commands rather than Publish them.